# HMAC signature for Amazon REST call incorrect on WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, amazon-product-api

Amazon have some [examples](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/rest-signature.html) of signing their REST calls with HMAC. However using the following code in a Metro / WinRT app the signatures don't match up.

Method to calculate the HMAC:

```
internal string CreateHMAC(
        string message,
        string algorithmName,
        string key)
    {
        MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);
        var binaryMessage = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(message, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var binaryKeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(binaryKeyMaterial);
        var binarySignedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, binaryMessage);
        var signedMessage = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(binarySignedMessage);
        return signedMessage;
    }
```

Test to check example:

```
var hmac = this.Amazon.CreateHMAC("GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06", "HMAC_SHA256", "1234567890");
var encoded = WebUtility.UrlEncode(hmac);
Assert.AreEqual("Nace%2BU3Az4OhN7tISqgs1vdLBHBEijWcBeCqL5xN9xg%3D", encoded);
```

And the actual result is:

```
M%2fy0%2bEAFFGaUAp4bWv%2fWEuXYah99pVsxvqtAuC8YN7I%3d
```

Has any one else successfully created an HMAC on WinRT? Or can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Documentation is incorrect/out of date - use [ecs.amazonaws.com](http://ecs.amazonaws.com) instead of [webservices.amazon.com](http://webservices.amazon.com)

So sign this:

> GET\necs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06

Sorry this is a really quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

The key in amazon is a Base64 string, so you need to convert this string to IBuffer object, but starting from already binary content exposed as Base 64 string. You are converting a normal string to binary wich is not the case.
try this

```
var algorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);

var binaryKeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(key);
var hmacKey = algorithmProvider.CreateKey(binaryKeyMaterial );
```

In this blog article I've wrote about [how to create the signature from WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juank/archive/2012/12/11/como-usar-mecanismos-firma-digital-windows-8-winrt.aspx) is in spanish but code is universal and you can translate it via bing translator or some others.