# I need to Hash a message with a key using Sha256 on windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, sha256

So in the old days I used to use System.Security.Cryptography which is not available in windows 8. what i found in windows 8 was windows.security
but i didn't find any examples on how to use Sha256 with a key.
This is the old code that I used with System.Security.Cryptography

```
        string appID = "appid";
        string key = "password";
        var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key));
        hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(appID));
        string k = "";
        foreach (byte test in hmacsha256.Hash)
        {
            k += test.ToString("X2");
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235959/hmac-signature-for-amazon-rest-call-incorrect-on-winrt

Comment: @CodesInChaos your comment helped me alot thank you very much.

Comment: Don't edit your final working code into the question. Post it as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create SHA-256 hashes in WinRT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503032/how-to-create-sha-256-hashes-in-winrt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the .NET Framework documentation, the class you used is available in .NET 4.5 and supported on Windows 8.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx

If you're talking about the WinRT runtime, this might be what you want:  http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Porting-to-WinRT/4df7586e1ef5400682eda00f0143b610

Answer (score 6):

So this is the final working code

```
public static string ComputeSignature (string algorithmName, string content, string key, BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)
{   
    var algorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);
    var contentBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(content, encoding);
    var keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, encoding);
    var signatureKey = algorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
    var signedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(signatureKey, contentBuffer);
    return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(signedBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classes in `Windows.Security.Cryptography` to create a message authentication code (a keyed hash in the question).  Here is an example.  Please treat it as demo code, provided as-is.  Do a full security review of all code associated with security.

```
var clear = "foobarbaz";
var bytes = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(clear, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
var macProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
var rndKey = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(macProvider.MacLength);
var key = macProvider.CreateKey(rndKey);
var cypherMac = CryptographicEngine.Sign(key, bytes);
var asString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(cypherMac);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;

string str = "your string";
string hash = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256).HashData(CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)));
```